# jQuery dialog that darkens the screen like the link dialog does here

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-1.3

I like the look of the link dialog here.  It darkens the screen and is probably modal (although I haven't tested that I just assume it is).  What's a quick and easy way of darkening the screen like that witha jQuery UI Dialog?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functionality you're talking about is provided by the [WYSIWYM Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)

To do it with jQuery UI's dialog, try this:

```
$("#something").dialog({ modal: true; });

<div id="something" title="modal dialog">
<p>Add your stuff here.</p>
</div>
```

It's not exactly the same by default, but I think it's even prettier. ;)

http://ui.jquery.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it is to have a div at z-order > 1 which covers the whole screen at less than 100% opacity

HTML:

```
<div id="cover>&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cover {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 10;
display: none;
background-color: #000000;
opacity: .7;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(opacity=.7);
```

}

Then you can show the cover when you show your dialog, which needs to be at a yet higher z-index and remove the cover at the same time as your dialog:

Open:

```
$("#cover").show();
$("#fileupload").show( "slow" );
```

Close:

```
$("#fileupload").fadeOut( "slow" );
$("#cover").hide();
```

Comment: A bit late, but I would change that `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`. When the user scrolls, the opacity background follow the screen and doesn't leave a big gap.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfectly valid thing to do and would be correct in many (most?) situations.